# Cannot add new controller on WebAPI project

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, visual-studio-2019

I was following an online class about ASP.Net Core WebAPI and when I try to add a new controller to my project I receive an error saying

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source'

[image]

I tried to download the newest version of ASP.Net Core (3.1) and to add a few NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc

But none of these worked.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try create manually?

Comment: what do you mean? I right-click the Controllers folder > Add > Controller > API Controller - Empty and then I get the error

Comment: You can add New item -> Class. Name it according to convention, add necessary attributes for routing if needed, similar to your existing controller - Voila! It should work.

Comment: Got same trouble. It doesn`t desapeared while i worked with this solution. Just create new class manually like @Ryan said above

Comment: Just restart the visual studio.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan and Mateech I'll add it manually then!

Comment: Trust me @XAMT , it was the very first thing I tried, and didn't work.